# Google Play schedule android app deliver

Tags: android, google-play

Is there any way to schedule my Android app availability on Google Play?

I need to make sure my app will be approved so my customer can work on the app's marketing.

Kind regards,
Bernardo

Comment: Your application has to be approved first, you can schedule when it can be purchased, that is that extent of your ability.

Comment: @Ramhound - No, it doesn't need to be approved; and no, you can't schedule it. When you upload it, it appears on the market. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

Google Play does not have an approval process. Just submit your app, and it'll show up within an hour to 24 hours in search results etc.

Just make sure you don't violate any policies with your app, otherwise it may be taken down, and possibly get your account banned with it.